# Missing selfRegister Lightning component

Tags: self-registration

I couldn't find the standard selfRegister lightning component and LightningSelfRegisterController. But, the selfRegister lightning component is used on the builder Register page. Is there any setting to be turned on to see this component.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Lakshmi

Comment: What do you mean, you can't find it? Where are you looking for it?

Comment: I wanted to update LightningSelfRegisterController to check first name is not null. So, I looked at apex class. but, it is not available.

Answer (score 0):

You should have Some Site created in your Salesforce org. Then only you will be able to see LightningSelfRegister* components in your Salesforce org. Please see below link for reference to create an experience cloud site. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_creating.htm&type=5

Comment: We have sites already and component is being used in register page of experience builder.